# Can I configure Dash to not erase the search when I change tabs?

Tags: unity-dash

Whenever I use the Dash, I want to start typing what I need to search and then look up for the tab on where I need to search it: whether it's Home, Applications, Files, Videos, etc.

By switching the tab the Dash erases what I had typed, and so I need to type it again in the next tab.

I am wondering if it's possible to have the Dash keep what I have typed whenever I hit the Ctrl + Tab.

Thank you.